# When you cut off all your ways back

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure, sentence-request

Imagine someone is working somewhere and is considered as one of the most efficient and high-ranking employees. Once after a quarrel over something with the boss who is the owner of the organization himself, the employee and the boss fight each other and the employee beats the boss up. Although he has been one of the best members of the team, when he is leaving the group, his colleagues are whispering:

> - He has cut off all his ways back.

Meaning that the guy has made a situation that he'll never be welcomed to return to his start point or his previous position etc.

Does the sentence above work naturally? If not, then please let me know what a native speaker would say instead.

P.S. I know all the related proverbs and sayings and I need to know the correct structure for this sentence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You sentence is grammatically correct, but nobody would say that. Probably the most idiomatic way of saying this would be

> He has [burned his bridges](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/burn+bridges).